# Mutual depend objects building with Mef

Tags: c#, mef

Let's say I have a class Application which imports a collection of plugins

```
public class Application : IApplication
{
    [ImportMany]
    private List<IPlugin> Plugins { get; set; }
}
```

And now my plugins are defined like this

```
    [Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
    public class Plugin : IPlugin
    {
        private IApplication _application;
    }
```

I would like to have in each plugin a reference to the IApplication which loaded the plugin.

How can I achieve that using Mef?

Answer (score 1):

Decorate the `Application` class with `[Export(typeof(IApplication))]`

Decorate the member variable `_application` in class `Plugin` with `[Import(typeof(IApplication))]`

Comment: Thanks. Could you please show me how you would then create the catalog and container so that plugins can be loaded from filesystem?

Comment: Follow this simple tutorial on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx

Comment: I made a simple case and it looks like it is working, now I have to understand why in my more complex situation it is not working